# Alphabetically Sort The State/Province Drop Down

Tags: sorting, json

I have an issue in sorting alphabetically those items in the state/region drop down.

```
// File: Mage/Directory/Helper/Data.php (line:150)
$json = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($regions); 
Mage::log($json);
```

I debugged above line and had checked the order in this var $json as expected. However, when json data comes to client-side, somehow that json object sorted itself based on the region_id. Is there a way to stop this auto-sort?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem in your case is not the code. It's the browser.
You can [read more about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5020699/2047249).

And here is a simple test you can run in the console.

```
var a = {1:'a', 3:'b', 2: 'c'};
console.log(a);
```

the result will be (at least on chrome and FF):

```
Object { 1="a", 2="c", 3="b"}
```

I was able to overcome this with the following trick.

In `js/varien/form.js` in the class `RegionUpdater` I added an other function to sort the region dropdown.

```
sortSelect : function (){
    elem = this.regionSelectEl;
    var tmpAry = new Array();
    var currentVal = $(elem).value;
    for (var i=0;i<$(elem).options.length;i++) {
        if (i == 0) continue;
        tmpAry[i-1] = new Array();
        tmpAry[i-1][0] = $(elem).options[i].text;
        tmpAry[i-1][1] = $(elem).options[i].value;
    }
    tmpAry.sort();
    while ($(elem).options.length > 0) {
       $(elem).options[0] = null;
    }
    for (var i=1;i<=tmpAry.length;i++) {
        var op = new Option(tmpAry[i-1][0], tmpAry[i-1][1]);
        $(elem).options[i] = op;
    }
    $(elem).value = currentVal;
    return;
}
```

and just call this function inside the `update` function of the same class.

Right before `if (this.disableAction=='hide') {` add this line

```
this.sortSelect();
```

Comment: appreciate for the effort you put in. Your code is worked. And, I hope one day this auto-sort on json object would be removed from all browsers and leave it to the programmer choice. *crossed fingers

Comment: Can you please guide me for Magento 2 file location ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you are exactly talking about. Where in magento, registration or checkout? But I'll try.

The regions are ordered by name by default:

```
\Mage_Directory_Model_Resource_Region_Collection::_construct
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('directory/region');

    $this->_countryTable    = $this->getTable('directory/country');
    $this->_regionNameTable = $this->getTable('directory/country_region_name');

    $this->addOrder('name', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
    $this->addOrder('default_name', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
}
```

So when your regions are not ordered, something is wrong.

You should check where the ordering is changed.

Comment: Apologize for unclear wording. The region I mentioned is at customer address form whereby customer can change the address detail. `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\customer\address\edit.phtml` and line 163

Comment: Plus for the example on how regions is actually sorted in the constructor.